# Running javascript on every element with css class not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am trying to run a javascript on every element on an asp.net page that has a certain CSS Class. I am not very proficient with javascript, so I don't know why it isn't working. I am dynamically creating controls and adding the CSS class to them, as well as the class is attached to a static control on the page.

I just want the controls to fade in after the page loads.

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.fadeInLoad').each(function (i, obj) {
            $(this).fadeIn();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.fadeInLoad
{
    color:#0d0d0d;
}
```

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: You don't need the `.each` loop -- just try `$('.fadeInLoad').fadeIn();`

Comment: _"I don't know why it isn't working"_ Can you describe "isn't working"? , include `html` at Question? Note, no `duration` appears as parameter to `.fadeIn()`; the elements would be displayed immediately

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library?

Comment: If you're adding the controls and/or classes after the page has loaded, then `$(document).ready` has already run and your code won't work anyway. You need to trigger the `fadeIn()` only after they've been added to the page, somehow.

Comment: Just in case anyone else in the future finds this helpful, I will respond to these questions.. The effect was not occurring at all. That is what I meant by not working. It literally did not do anything. The Jquery library was included. The controls were being created dynamically before page_load during the page_init event, so the $(document).ready was valid. I've marked the answer that fixed my problem below. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `display` to `none` on the class rule. Otherwise it is trying to fade in an element that is already visible.

Also, as @Blazemonger has pointed out, just call `.fadeIn()` directly on the jQuery selector call.

**Here is an example**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fadeInLoad').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

```css
.fadeInLoad {
  color: #0d0d0d;
  display: none; /* This display needs to be here */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Does not fade in</div>
<div class="fadeInLoad">Fades In</div>
<div class="fadeInLoad">Fades In</div>
<div class="fadeInLoad">Fades In</div>
<div class="fadeInLoad">Fades In</div>
<div class="fadeInLoad">Fades In</div>
<div class="fadeInLoad">Fades In</div>
<div class="fadeInLoad">Fades In</div>
```

Comment: The problem was that I did not have display: none in my CSS Class. I added that in and it works like a charm now. Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

For me it's working. This nodes with that class dadeInLoad are in source of page or are loading with some Ajax?

There is working demo:

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Dominik_Wilk/wn7owf90/1/)

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.fadeInLoad').each(function (i, obj) {
            $(this).fadeIn(3000);
        });
    });
```